# A tensor summation question

Tags: notation, tensor-calculus

With the definition of the tensor:

\begin{equation} J_{ij} = I_{ij} - \tfrac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}I^{k}_{k}, \qquad i,j,k\in\{1,2,3\},
 \end{equation}

I have seen the quantity:
\begin{equation}
J_{ij}J_{ij}
\end{equation}
written as:
\begin{equation}
I_{ij}I_{ij} - \tfrac{1}{3}I_{ii}I_{jj}.
\end{equation}

How is this possible?

Comment: You're using rather confusing notation. Are you summing over i and j? The repeated lower indices are pretty ambiguous.

Comment: Some sources use $J^{ij}J_{ij}$ and some use $J_{ij}J_{ij}$ to represent the same thing. I don't understand why.

Comment: In Euclidean space, it's not ambiguous and of course summation is implied.

Comment: Because using upper indices represent vectors while lower indices represent covectors. They are functionals of each other. Using all lower indices is ambiguous because you can't tell which is which.

Comment: But it's *only* unambiguous when the metric is Euclidean, so getting into the habit of writing everything with lower indices is a bad idea. It also looks sloppier.

Comment: @elfmotat By 'Euclidean' do you mean 'the spatial part of the Minkowski metric tensor'?

Comment: Yes. Flat 3D space is usually called 'Euclidean.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's define $I=I^k_{~k}$ to make things look nicer. We have:

$$J_{ij}J^{ij}=(I_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}I)(I^{ij}-\frac{1}{3}\delta^{ij}I)$$
$$=I_{ij}I^{ij}-\frac{1}{3}I^{ij}\delta_{ij}I-\frac{1}{3}I_{ij}\delta^{ij}I+\frac{1}{9}\delta_{ij}\delta ^{ij}I^2$$

The second two terms are equal (they're just scalars), so:

$$J_{ij}J^{ij}=I_{ij}I^{ij}-\frac{2}{3}I^{ij}\delta_{ij}I+\frac{1}{9}\delta_{ij}\delta ^{ij}I^2$$

Now, $\delta_{ij}\delta ^{ij}=D$ where $D$ is the number of dimensions of the manifold. I assume we're using a 3D manifold, so $\delta_{ij}\delta ^{ij}=3$. This simplifies the above to:

$$J_{ij}J^{ij}=I_{ij}I^{ij}-\frac{2}{3}I^{ij}\delta_{ij}I+\frac{1}{3}I^2$$

Since apparently the metric is Euclidean (as was discussed in the comments above), $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ and therefore $I^{ij}\delta_{ij}=I^i_{~i}=I$. So everything reduces to:

$$J^{ij}J_{ij}=I^{ij}I_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}I^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Just square and work out the different contributions:

$$\left(\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}I_{kk}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{9} \delta_{ij}^2 I_{kk}^2 = \frac{1}{3} I_{ii}I_{jj}$$
since $\delta_{ij}^2 = 3.$

The cross terms yield

$$-\frac{2}{3}\delta_{ij}I_{ij}I_{kk} = -\frac{2}{3} I_{ii}I_{jj}.$$

Voilà!

Comment: Why do you have $I_{kk}$?

Comment: @user16307 The difference between upper and lower indices vanishes for using $(x,y,z)$ coordinates (and pretty much nothing else, as mentioned elsewhere), so $I_{kk}$ is another way of writing $I^k_k$ *in this special case*. So as long as your source has all $i$'s and $j$'s lowered (and is therefore ruining a beautiful aspect of this notation, imo), consistency dictates you should use $I_{kk}$ rather than $I^k_k$ (or $I^k{}_k$), as Vibert has done.